# TypeError: verify_file() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data_filename' (GNUPG)

Tags: python, django, class, gnupg

I am working with gnupg in a PythonAnywhere-Django environment to run Mayan EDMS. I recently changed from using `python-gnupg` to the standard `gnupg` as to finally overcome OSErrors. However, I have found out that some syntax needs to be changed due to this process (i.e., `gnupghome>homedir`; `gpgbinary>binary`, etc.). Has anyone ever encountered the correct replacement for `data_filename` in the `verify_file` command for gnupg? I have been browsing online for some time and have seen users only inputting two arguments, as opposed to the three I use now. The file name is vital to my code.

**Traceback**

```
2019-06-13 07:22:26,695: Unexpected exception while trying to create version for new document "testassayform.xlsx" from source "Default"; verify_file() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data_filename'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mywebsite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mayan/apps/sources/models/base.py", line 128, in upload_document
    file_object=file_object, _user=user,
  File "/home/mywebsite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mayan/apps/documents/models/document_models.py", line 160, in new_version
    document_version.save(_user=_user)
  File "/home/mywebsite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mayan/apps/documents/models/document_version_models.py", line 291, in save
    document_version=self
  File "/home/mywebsite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mywebsite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 394, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/home/mywebsite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mayan/apps/document_signatures/models.py", line 111, in save
    file_object=file_object
  File "/home/mywebsite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mayan/apps/django_gpg/managers.py", line 118, in verify_file
    file_object=file_object, keys=keys
  File "/home/mywebsite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mayan/apps/django_gpg/classes.py", line 120, in verify_file
    keys=keys, data_filename=data_filename
  File "/home/mywebsite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mayan/apps/django_gpg/classes.py", line 82, in gpg_command
    result = function(gpg=gpg, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mywebsite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mayan/apps/django_gpg/classes.py", line 56, in _verify_file
    file=file_object, data_filename=data_filename
TypeError: verify_file() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data_filename'
2019-06-13 07:22:26,781: Error executing document upload task; verify_file() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data_filename', <class 'TypeError'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mywebsite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mayan/apps/sources/views.py", line 277, in forms_valid
    user_id=user_id,
  File "/home/mywebsite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 565, in apply_async
    link=link, link_error=link_error, **options)
  File "/home/mywebsite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 763, in apply
    request=request, propagate=throw)
  File "/home/mywebsite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 355, in eager_trace_task
    uuid, args, kwargs, request)
  File "/home/mywebsite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 253, in trace_task
    I, R, state, retval = on_error(task_request, exc, uuid)
  File "/home/mywebsite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mywebsite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mayan/apps/sources/tasks.py", line 159, in task_source_handle_upload
    shared_uploaded_file_id=shared_upload.pk, **kwargs
  File "/home/mywebsite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 461, in delay
    return self.apply_async(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/mywebsite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 565, in apply_async
    link=link, link_error=link_error, **options)
  File "/home/mywebsite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 763, in apply
    request=request, propagate=throw)
  File "/home/mywebsite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 355, in eager_trace_task
    uuid, args, kwargs, request)
  File "/home/mywebsite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 253, in trace_task
    I, R, state, retval = on_error(task_request, exc, uuid)
  File "/home/mywebsite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mywebsite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mayan/apps/sources/tasks.py", line 193, in task_upload_document
    querystring=querystring, user=user,
  File "/home/mywebsite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mayan/apps/sources/models/base.py", line 128, in upload_document
    file_object=file_object, _user=user,
  File "/home/mywebsite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mayan/apps/documents/models/document_models.py", line 160, in new_version
    document_version.save(_user=_user)
  File "/home/mywebsite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mayan/apps/documents/models/document_version_models.py", line 291, in save
    document_version=self
  File "/home/mywebsite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mywebsite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 394, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/home/mywebsite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mayan/apps/document_signatures/models.py", line 111, in save
    file_object=file_object
  File "/home/mywebsite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mayan/apps/django_gpg/managers.py", line 118, in verify_file
    file_object=file_object, keys=keys
  File "/home/mywebsite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mayan/apps/django_gpg/classes.py", line 120, in verify_file
    keys=keys, data_filename=data_filename
  File "/home/mywebsite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mayan/apps/django_gpg/classes.py", line 82, in gpg_command
    result = function(gpg=gpg, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mywebsite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mayan/apps/django_gpg/classes.py", line 56, in _verify_file
    file=file_object, data_filename=data_filename
TypeError: verify_file() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data_filename'
```

**classes.py (relevant function)**

```
def verify_file(self, file_object, keys, data_filename=None):
        return self.gpg_command(
            function=PythonGNUPGBackend._verify_file, file_object=file_object,
            keys=keys, data_filename=data_filename
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply removed the verify file function altogether to bypass this problem.

However, due to further restrictions in the conversion process, I do not recommend pursuing a similar workflow as Mayan EDMS requires LibreOffice, which requires a machine or specialized host which provides that.